# Understanding why Firestore listen method sends two requests when using rules and a get function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get, emulation, rules

I'm currently facing an issue with Firestore where the listen method in combination with the get function is sending two requests instead of one. Let me explain my setup and the rules I've defined:

I have a sub-collection of messages within a chat document, and I'm using the listen method to listen for real-time updates on the messages collection. Here's an example of the rules and the code I'm using:

```
match /friends_chats/{chatId} {
  allow read:  if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants ;
  // Other rules for write, update, delete

  // Messages subcollection
  match /messages/{messageId} {
    allow list: if isChatParticipant() && request.query.limit<=10 ;

    function isChatParticipant() {
      return debug(request.auth.uid in debug(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/friends_chats/$(chatId)).data.participants));
    }
  }
}
```

```
CollectionReference subMessagesRef = documentChange.Document.Reference
                        .Collection("messages");

Query sq = subMessagesRef.LimitToLast(10).OrderBy("createdAt");
                    
// Listen for real-time updates on the sub-messages collection
ListenerRegistration subMessagesRegistration = sq.Listen(subMessagesSnapshot =>
{
  // Handle snapshot changes
});
```

While the second request accomplishes my task I don't understand why on my emulator is showing double request with the first one in error. (removing the get from the rule also remove the first request ).

[image]
[image]

I was expecting the emulator to don't show me that request going into error.

EDIT: image with db regarding the chat/messages. This is the log from the debugs in rules ( results are as expected ) :

```
list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "9CjKH7cqyyMc3OBDm4A1X6yEZu23"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "ZyOwVGXKkFQyMyPUPPE8XZAcryb2"
  }
}

bool_value: true
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: So the request succeeds? If so this may be a bug, please file an issue in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose